# 12.10 My unity doesnt start after restart

Tags: unity, 12.10, autostart

I have installed 12.10 x64 on my laptop today. After installation it started normally, after restart for updates it started normally, but after next restart (and every else) it strat only empty screen with no taskbar or icons and in low resolution. My unity plugin in ccsm is enabled. Do you have any idea how to fix it? Or anybody else in similar trouble?

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is that some conflict occurred in your window manager settings and you might need to tweak the GUI a bit. Ubuntu Tweak should do the trick, or some other settings editor. Just make sure that the Unity taskbar is enabled.

Comment: ubuntu tweak is just for settings of unity. my problem is that unity doesnt start. i can only use apps that i can run from terminal (ctrl-alt-t). btw what is right command to start unity manually? thanks